# How to serialize a list back into it's original binary Database?

Tags: python, database, serialization, binary

I'm trying to make a proper serializer for binary `scores.db` and `collections.db` for a game called osu!,

I first used a parser found here https://github.com/KirkSuD/osudb
Which allowed me to parse my db files into list that I can edit but I haven't seen any up to date serializer that I can use to serialize the data back into a new binary, so I tried making one myself.

I know that I can just replace `struct.unpack(format,v1)` by just `struct.pack(format,v1)`, but here
is the first issue:

I can't read a defined amount of bytes anymore since they just aren't bytes and I also can't do that for obvious reasons, which means I also can't use the opposite technique the dev of the parser used (to parse the data easily).

Right now, I have converted the binary to `str` for vizualition

https://controlc.com/6cdcffa3 I need to obtain that from https://controlc.com/9ddc4af1

I need to get the exact same format, the issue being that, I started making this:

```py
def serialize_types_exp(fobj, data_type):
    if data_type == "Int": ## 4 bytes unsigned int
        return struct.pack("<I", fobj)

def Serialize_score_exp(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as fobj:
        with open("./osu!MapSync/output_func.txt", "r+") as otp:
            otp.truncate(0)
            for i in fobj:
                fobj = ast.literal_eval(i)
            print(type(fobj))
            f=0
            while f <= 1:
                res = str(serialize_types_exp(fobj[f], "Int"))
                if f == 0:
                    print(fobj[f],"->",res[0:-1])
                    otp.write(str(res)[0:-1])
                else:
                    print(fobj[f],"->",res[2:-1])
                    otp.write(str(res)[2:-1])
                f += 1

Serialize_score_exp('./osu!MapSync/output.txt')
```

Which I realized, would basically be the same thing as just returning the string I want aKa:

```py
def Serialize_score_exp(filepath):
    return "litteraly a static result copy pasted from the binary file"
```

Which isn't what I want, so I wonder what can I use to serialize it back to the format I want?

EDIT: here are the files if any of you want to try something
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qmam_u9mVfqxBZ_U5QvFnq1t_01yOQzT/view?usp=sharing

EDIT 02/01/2020: It seem like directly writing the binary to a file using wb and then reading it back solve most of the visualization issue, but before i continue, there are `\x0b`  bytes (space included) in the original serialized data, and i don't know how to obtain these from my list, any idea?

here is my code right now

```py
def serialize_type_exp(fobj, data_type):
    if data_type == "Boolean": ## False if 0x00 else True
        return struct.pack("<?", fobj)
    elif data_type == "Byte": ## 1 byte int
        return struct.pack("<s", fobj)
    elif data_type == "Double": ## 8 bytes floating point
        return struct.pack("<d", fobj)
    elif data_type == "Int": ## 4 bytes unsigned int
        return struct.pack("<I", fobj)
    elif data_type == "Long": ## 8 bytes unsigned int
        return struct.pack("<Q", fobj)
    elif data_type == "Short": ## 2 bytes unsigned int
        return struct.pack("<H", fobj)
    elif data_type == "Single": ## 4 bytes floating point
        return struct.pack("<f", fobj)
    elif data_type == "String": ## 0x00 or 0x0b - ULE128(n) - UTF-8(length=n)
        bb = fobj
        if bb == None:
            return None
        return fobj.encode("utf-8")
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('parse_type(fobj, data_type): Unknown data type: "%s".' % data_type)

def serialize_types_exp(fobj, types):
    return [serialize_type_exp(fobj, i) for i in types]

score_data_types = ['Byte', 'Int', 'String', 'String', 'String', 'Short', 'Short', 'Short', 'Short', 'Short', 'Short', 'Int', 'Short', 'Boolean', 'Int', 'String', 'Long', 'Int', 'Long']

def serialize_scoredb_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as fobj:
        with open("./osu!MapSync/output_func.db", "wb") as otp:
            otp.truncate(0)
            for i in fobj:
                fobj = ast.literal_eval(i)
            for i in range(2):
                otp.write((serialize_type_exp(fobj[i],'Int')))
            for maps in fobj[2]:
                for i in range(2):
                    if type(maps[i]) == str:
                        otp.write(serialize_type_exp(maps[i],'String'))
                    if type(maps[i]) == int:
                        otp.write(serialize_type_exp(maps[i],'Int'))
                for scores in maps[2]:
                    for idx, stats in enumerate(scores): 
                        if score_data_types[idx] == 'Byte':
                            print(stats,"->",stats.to_bytes,":",type(bytes(stats)))
                            print(type(serialize_type_exp(bytes(stats), score_data_types[idx])))
                            otp.write(serialize_type_exp(bytes(stats), score_data_types[idx]))
                        else:
                            otp.write(serialize_type_exp(stats, score_data_types[idx]))

serialize_scoredb_data('./osu!MapSync/output.txt')
```

EDIT 3: fixed that `\x0b` and `\x0b`  bytes, now i have to face one more problem before it work ingame:
some bytes seems to have changed from `\x00` to `\x01` in the process and i don't know why

```py
import osudb
import ast
import struct

with open("./osu!MapSync/scores.db", "rb") as f:
    with open("Exp.txt", "w") as i:
        for stuff in f:
            i.write(str(stuff))

parse = osudb.parse_score(r"./osu!MapSync/scores.db")
with open('./osu!MapSync/output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(parse)) #[1:-1].split(',')

def serialize_type_exp(fobj, data_type):
    if data_type == "Boolean": ## False if 0x00 else True
        return struct.pack("<?", fobj)
    elif data_type == "Byte": ## 1 byte int
        return struct.pack("<s", fobj)
    elif data_type == "Double": ## 8 bytes floating point
        return struct.pack("<d", fobj)
    elif data_type == "Int": ## 4 bytes unsigned int
        return struct.pack("<I", fobj)
    elif data_type == "Long": ## 8 bytes unsigned int
        return struct.pack("<Q", fobj)
    elif data_type == "Short": ## 2 bytes unsigned int
        return struct.pack("<H", fobj)
    elif data_type == "Single": ## 4 bytes floating point
        return struct.pack("<f", fobj)
    elif data_type == "String": ## 0x00 or 0x0b - ULE128(n) - UTF-8(length=n)
        bb = fobj
        if bb == None:
            return None
        return fobj.encode("utf-8")
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('parse_type(fobj, data_type): Unknown data type: "%s".' % data_type)

def serialize_types_exp(fobj, types):
    return [serialize_type_exp(fobj, i) for i in types]

score_data_types = ['Byte', 'Int', 'String', 'String', 'String', 'Short', 'Short', 'Short', 'Short', 'Short', 'Short', 'Int', 'Short', 'Boolean', 'Int', 'String', 'Long', 'Int', 'Long']

def serialize_scoredb_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as fobj:
        with open("./new osu!.db/scores.db", "wb") as otp:
            otp.truncate(0)
            for i in fobj:
                fobj = ast.literal_eval(i)
            for i in range(2):
                otp.write((serialize_type_exp(fobj[i],'Int')))
            for maps in fobj[2]:
                for i in range(2):
                    if type(maps[i]) == str:
                        otp.write(b'\x0b '+serialize_type_exp(maps[i],'String'))
                    if type(maps[i]) == int:
                        otp.write(serialize_type_exp(maps[i],'Int'))
                for scores in maps[2]:
                    for idx, stats in enumerate(scores): 
                        if score_data_types[idx] == 'Byte':
                            otp.write(serialize_type_exp(bytes(stats), score_data_types[idx]))
                        elif stats == None:
                            otp.write(b'\x00')
                        elif score_data_types[idx] == 'String' and len(stats) == 32:
                            otp.write(b'\x0b '+serialize_type_exp(stats, score_data_types[idx]))
                        elif idx == 3:
                            otp.write(b'\x0b\x06'+serialize_type_exp(stats, score_data_types[idx]))
                        else:    
                            otp.write(serialize_type_exp(stats, score_data_types[idx]))

serialize_scoredb_data('./osu!MapSync/output.txt')

with open("./osu!MapSync/output_func.db", "rb") as f:
    with open("output_func.txt", "w") as i:
        for stuff in f:
            i.write(str(stuff))
```

this is what i want https://controlc.com/6cdcffa3 and this is what i obtained https://controlc.com/4e547b64

already, fixed the parser i used, now i discovered that the formatting on the username is incorrect and is variable from a player to another, i apparently need to add this to my serializer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128#Encode_unsigned_integer
except i i have no idea about what they mean about `set high order bit of byte;` and how to do it in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i'm finally done with the serializer and merging part so the final step of my project will be to implement FTP properly in hope that it will work on every device (android included), so this topic isn't necessary anymore, all the code is published on github rn

https://github.com/Mrcubix/Osu-MapSync